# How to assign the values for the parameters

Tags: objective-c

How to assign the values for the parameters.

```
Rs232MsgRawEncoded(const int nMsgId,const INT8U* pSrc=NULL,unsigned int nSize=0);
```

I have declared the above cpp method declaration in Objective C as the following

```
-(id)initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded:(const int)nMsgId withpSrc:(const uint8_t*)pSrc withSize:(unsigned int)nSize;
```

Inside the function i'm checking whether its null or with some value.

I could not able to declare the variables as pSrc=NULL and nSize=0 in the Objective C
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-c (as well as c) does not support default parameters for functions.

So you can either use the function you have and pass all parameters to it every time. If you don't - create new functions with some parameters omitted and call your 'main' function with default parameters inside, e.g.:

```
-(id)initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded:(const int)nMsgId{
    return [self initWithRS232MsgRawEncoded:nMsgId withpSrc:NULL withSize:0];
}
```